# How to prevent the transmission of escape via CTRL + V

Tags: c#, escaping, richtextbox, copy-paste

how to filter <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in richTextBox?

I have richtextbox with text "blabla \n bla...\n -gg".

I can not allow it to hit \ n through the copy \ paste.

How to do this?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive from `RichTextBox` and override `ProcessCmdKey`.

```
class NoPasteRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    { 
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V) &&
            Clipboard.GetText().Contains("\n"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you completely forbid CTRL + V. and I need only when the text contains \ n.